# How to change center frequency automatically in GRC?

Tags: software-defined-radio, gnuradio

I'm on reasearch using USRP and GNU radio for solar flare observation. The research is making digital radio receiver in GNU radio companion and using USRP B200. Basically the purpose of system is to receive multi-frequency which in range frequency 45-870 MHz. The problem is i can't receive signal execpt of center frequency. I want the system could be able to scan signal in those range frequency above. I want to change center frequency automatically in periodically but i don't know how the way. I'm an amateur and i haven't basic using GRC. I hope someone can help me and give me reference to solve the problem.

Regards,
Sinta.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!  Please consider taking [the tour](http://ham.stackexchange.com/tour) to get the most from the site.

Answer (score 2):

That's something that is inherently hard to implement in a graphical tool. It's a very sequential program flow, and thus, the GRC approach might be the wrong one – while relatively easy to write in python, it'd be hard to do this graphically. The graphical approach to software design isn't always the easiest one (sorry, LabVIEW).

So, I'd recommend going through the Guided Tutorials on http://tutorials.gnuradio.org . Afterwards, take the python code that GRC generates out of your graphical flow graph, and amend it such that it simply is restarted with different frequencies.